# how do I change id for Single File Components in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to use [single file component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) code style as following code in vue

**item.vue**

```
<template>
    <item v-if="value">
</template>
<script>
   export default {
      name: 'item',...</script>
...
</script>
<style>...</style>
```

its OK but as you see I have used item component Recursively but [there is problem with recursive components](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3039) and they say I have to use different name and id as following code to fix this problem

```
Vue.component('id', {
    name: 'internal-name',
    ...
})
```

so how do I set different name and id in item.vue with its code style?

Answer (score 0):

The id is only set when you make the component globaly available in the parent by using the `Vue.component('id', {...})` command. The name is an optional part of a component. 
The given solution in the issue with `Vue.component('id', Vue.extend({...}))` seems to be worth a try.